# how to use phpList with external (3rd party) SMTP servers

Tags: smtp, phplist

Like the title says I am trying to have phpList on my server and relay the messages through 3rd party service (e.g. TurboSMTP.com). I am having trouble finding any setting in the application or in any of the config files to allow me to set this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available under the **config.php** file which is under the folder **/lists/config**

Scroll down to the mailer settings

Search for the following code and modify your smtp hostname. Hope this helps.

```
# If you want to use the PHPMailer class from phpmailer.sourceforge.net, set the following
# to 1. If you tend to send out html emails, it is recommended to do so.
define("PHPMAILER",1);

# To use a SMTP please give your server hostname here, leave it blank to use the standard
# PHP mail() command.
define("PHPMAILERHOST",'');

# if you want to use smtp authentication when sending the email uncomment the following
# two lines and set the username and password to be the correct ones
#$phpmailer_smtpuser = 'smtpuser';
#$phpmailer_smtppassword = 'smtppassword';
```

Answer (score 2):

lists/config/config.php does not always contain all fine-tune settings. See config/config_extended.php

```
# in the above you can specify multiple SMTP servers like this:
# 'server1:port1;server2:port2;server3:port3' eg
#define('PHPMAILERHOST','smtp1.mydomain.com:25;smtp2.mydomain.com:2500;smtp3.phplist.com:5123');

# if you want to use smtp authentication when sending the email uncomment the following
# two lines and set the username and password to be the correct ones
#$phpmailer_smtpuser = 'smtpuser';
#$phpmailer_smtppassword = 'smtppassword';

## you can set this to send out via a different SMTP port
# define('PHPMAILERPORT',25);
```